# JSON LD Transformation : to remove certain objects from json with context or jsonld framing

Tags: jsonschema, schema.org, json-ld

I have a JSON with the following structure and I am looking to remove certain parts of it either by using JSON-LD Context or JSON-LD Framing so in this situation I need a specific type2 only in the output along with the parent

```
{
   "@context":{
      "@vocab":"http://xyz.abc.com/01#",
      "sdf":"http://xyz.abc.com/01#",
      "@base":"http://xyz.abc.com/01#",
      "rowid":"@id",
      "values":"@nest",
      "type":"@type"
   },
   "@id":"sdf:parent",
   "type":"type1",
   "values":[
      {
         "value":984657
      }
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "rowid":"5637220",
         "type":"type2",
         "values":[
            {
               "value":"i am type 2"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "rowid":"9847589",
         "type":"type3",
         "values":[
            {
               "value":"I am type 3"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

So the output should look somewhat like this with the child either embedded in the parent or separate like below with a predicate hasChild

```
{
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "http://xyz.abc.com/01#parent",
      "@type": "http://xyz.abc.com/01#type1",
      "http://xyz.abc.com/01#value": 984657 ,
      "hasChild" : "http://xyz.abc.com/5637220"
    },
    {
      "@id": "http://xyz.abc.com/5637220",
      "@type": "http://xyz.abc.com/01#type2",
      "http://xyz.abc.com/01#value": "i am type 2"
    }
  ]
}
```